# oracle can't sort data in special persian characters

Tags: oracle, persian

I set oracle language to persian and store data as persian's characters in oracle Database,but when I sort data grid in oracle  it can't sort by some special persian character like 'چ-گ-پ-ژ', in other words oracle does not sort  data grid by this charactres:'چ-گ-پ-ژ'. 
can anyone help me?

Comment: Which client are you using - SQL Developer? What is the territory/language/character set in your client; and what are the other NLS settings, particularly NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP? (In SQL Developer, look in Tools->Preferences->Database->NLS; or query the `nls_session_parameters` view).

Comment: did you add order by clause on your script

Comment: It's described here in Persian: http://mghaffari.blog.ir/post/218

Comment: NLS_SORT  : BINARY
NLS_COMP : BINARY
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET : AL16UTF16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 point and if you do theses be sure your Persian sorting would be works as well


**1.** Before installation of Oracle you should set your language in your OS (Persian Preferred)

**2.** After installation of Oracle find `NLS_LANG` key in OS Registry and change it to `AR8MSWIN1256`

Answer (score 0):

You must add persian sort by "locale builder" ({ORACLE_HOME}/nls/lbuilder/lbuilder) tool then by nlt file generate nlb files(almost 5 files generated) then copy them to {ORACLE_HOME}/nls/data and done.

Creating a sort order may be time consuming because you must specify major and minor order per character.
You can use arabic sort file (lx30015.nlb) as base sort file then save as nlt file and name it as persian_sort then add or verify the order of these characters: 'چ-گ-پ-ژ' and ک ك ی ي